# Certificates and Provisioning Profiles - No Code Signing Identity Found

Tags: certificate, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I will try to be as explicit as I possibly can to make it shorter:

I try to compare 2 situations:

1. The first client creates his own certificate. I receive from the client the developer password and create an app id, and then I create a provisioning profile for development . All works perfect.
2. Another client, just like in previous case, creates his own certificate. I only receive an invite as a team member, and I ask the client to create the provisioning profile for development himself. I download and install the developer provisioning profile, yet I can't use it to create an archive due to no code signing identity found error.

How is it possible that I can use the first developer certificate just fine to create an archive, without providing the client with any keys/details, yet I can't use the second client certificate and I can't find any signing identities in keychain or in Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details?

I did click from XCode to request a new certificate from the client when I tried to use a wildcard development certificate, and I can see the certificate pending approval in the certificates list. But I really don't want to put the client into the process of creating another development certificate and use the certificate that I requested via xcode and that I will ask him to approve, unless I am 100% sure that this is the only way to make it work.

Also, I get told form XCode that I already have a valid certificate in my mac, but if I want I can revoke and request one again.

But again, how is it possible that in first situation it works just fine, and in second it doesn't.

Please help with this problem, hopefully someone will be kind enough to understand exactly the situation I am facing.